# Atomic moving average on image

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to calculate an atomic moving average on an image, but the average is wrong and when i'm running it with the same data multiple times the average is different every time.
I have a RGBA8 texture but i'm binding it as a R32UI because i need both atomic operations and texture filtering.

I made a test app for the averaging because the actual application is very complex. In the test app I'm doing the averaging in a fragment shader on a single texel, so I have a 1x1 RGBA8 texture, bound as R32UI. I'm rendering a quad with a size of 500x500 and each fragment shader invocation is adding a blue or a red value to the average in the texel, depending on the fragment coordinate.

fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout (binding = 0, r32ui) volatile uniform uimage2D img;

layout (location = 0) uniform int width;

vec4 convRGBA8ToVec4( uint val)
{
    return vec4(float((val & 0x000000FF)), float((val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8U),
                float((val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16U), float((val & 0xFF000000) >> 24U));
}

uint convVec4ToRGBA8( vec4 val)
{
    return (uint(val.w) & 0x000000FF) << 24U | (uint(val.z) & 0x000000FF) << 16U |
           (uint(val.y) & 0x000000FF) << 8U  | (uint(val.x) & 0x000000FF);
}

void imageAtomicRGBA8Avg(layout (r32ui) volatile uimage2D imgUI, ivec2 coords , vec4 val)
{
    val.rgb *= 255.0f;
    uint newVal = convVec4ToRGBA8(val);
    uint prevStoredVal = 0;
    uint curStoredVal;

    // Loop as long as destination value gets changed by other threads
    while((curStoredVal = imageAtomicCompSwap(imgUI, coords, prevStoredVal, newVal))
          != prevStoredVal)
    {
        prevStoredVal = curStoredVal;
        vec4 unpacked = convRGBA8ToVec4(curStoredVal);
        vec3 x = unpacked.xyz;
        float n = unpacked.w;
        vec4 curValF = vec4(vec3(((n * x) + val.xyz) / n), n + 1);
        newVal = convVec4ToRGBA8(curValF);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int idx = int(gl_FragCoord.y * width) + int(gl_FragCoord.x);

    if(idx % 2 == 0)
    {
        // Add red
        imageAtomicRGBA8Avg(img, ivec2(0, 0), vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    }
    else
    {
        // Add blue
        imageAtomicRGBA8Avg(img, ivec2(0, 0), vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    }
}
```

the average color is somewhere between red and blue, sometimes it's even pure red or blue. I wonder why that is happening, i found the averaging function in a paper so it actually should work.

Here's the init code:

```
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 1, 1);

glBindTextureUnit(0, texture);
glBindImageTexture(0, texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32UI);
```

and the rendering code:

```
glUseProgram(atomic_avg_prog);
glUniform1i(0, window_width);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glUseProgram(read_prog);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

The read program is simply drawing the texel on a quad

Comment: "*Loop as long as destination value gets changed by other threads*" What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm calculating the next average, but if some other thread was faster and wrote a new average in that time, i need to throw the average away, pick the new average which was written and calculate it again

Comment: And you don't see how this might lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: it doesn't, in the worst case one thread would wait for all other threads to finish, but in the actual application there will be at most 5 collisions. Performance is not a problem. If a thread needs to wait it's because some other threads finished, so all threads will finish sooner or later

Comment: "*in the worst case one thread would wait for all other threads to finish*" Now show me the part of the GLSL specification that allows one thread to "wait for all other threads to finish". Or more specifically, the part that *ensures* that separate threads act independently and therefore allow one thread to wait for others to finish. Because I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist in the standard. Or in GPU hardware. If this managed to produce a result, you simply got lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing `convRGBA8ToVec4` and `convVec4ToRGBA8` with `packUnorm4x8` and `unpackUnorm4x8`, thanks to this article: https://rauwendaal.net/2013/02/07/glslrunningaverage/

The solution doesn't allow to average more than 255 values because of the counter being stored in the alpha with only 8 bits, but in my case that's enough

```
void imageAtomicAvgRGBA8(layout (r32ui) volatile uimage2D imgUI, ivec2 coords , vec4 val)
{
    uint newVal = packUnorm4x8(vec4(val.xyz, 1.0f / 255.0f));
    uint prevStoredVal = 0;
    uint curStoredVal;

    // Loop as long as destination value gets changed by other threads
    while((curStoredVal = imageAtomicCompSwap(imgUI, coords, prevStoredVal, newVal))
          != prevStoredVal)
    {
        prevStoredVal = curStoredVal;
        vec4 unpacked = unpackUnorm4x8(curStoredVal);
        vec3 x = unpacked.xyz;

        float n = unpacked.w * 255.0f;

        x = (x * n + val.xyz) / (n + 1);
        newVal = packUnorm4x8(vec4(x, (n + 1) / 255.0f));
    }
}
```